# do this using recursion only

Tags: c, function, recursion, definition

Write a recursive function evenDigits that accepts an integer parameter n and returns a new integer containing only the even digits from n, in the same order. If n does not contain any even digits, return 0.

For example, the call of evenDigits(8342116) should return 8426 and the call of evenDigits(35179) should return 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, together with a description of how it doesn't work.

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to implement this yourself. To give more focus have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: hint: `evenDigits(8342116)` ==> `8000000 + evenDigits(342116)` ... beware negative values (or change requirements to "function that accepts **unsigned** integer parameter")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my five cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evenDigits( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    int digit = n % Base;

    int even = digit % 2 == 0;

    if ( !even ) digit = 0;

    return ( n /= Base ) == 0 ? digit 
                              : ( even ? Base : 1 ) * evenDigits( n ) + digit;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "evenDigits( 8342116 ) = %d\n", evenDigits( 8342116 ) );
    printf( "evenDigits( -8342116 ) = %d\n", evenDigits( -8342116 ) );
    printf( "evenDigits( 35179 ) = %d\n", evenDigits( 35179 ) );
    printf( "evenDigits( -35179 ) = %d\n", evenDigits( -35179 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
evenDigits( 8342116 ) = 8426
evenDigits( -8342116 ) = -8426
evenDigits( 35179 ) = 0
evenDigits( -35179 ) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve recursion, you need to apply a *Y Combinator*.

Make sure to implement end recursion optimization for complex problems, which trivial implementations of the Y Combinator usually don't. Depending on your compiler vendor, there probably are low-level hooks into the appropriate stage 2 and 3 optimization steps, which you then need to integrate into your actual recursion implementation.

Assuming you already have implemented recursion as part of a macro `letfn`, you could go about the problem at hand like this:

```
(fn f (input)
  (letfn g (remainder shift result)
    (let (next_even_digit next_remainder) (fetch_next_even_digit remainder shift)
      (if next_even_digit
        (g next_remainder (* shift 10) (+ result (* shift next_even_digit)))
        result))))
```

I'll leave the trivial implementation of `fetch_next_even_digit` up to the reader.

Comment: I can only think of two reasons to write an answer like this to a question like this. One is rather unkind towards OP, the other towards you. (The downvote is however not by me.)

Comment: Monthly SO humor check failed as usual :)

Comment: Did you mistake StackOverflow for a site in which making unhelpful, unkind answers to off-topic questions of new users is considered to be humorous?

Comment: o@Yunnosch You are wrong. Your point of view is very limited. Most pf participants are here to spend their time doing something interesting for example an assignment for them themselves. It is totally unimportant whether it is a home  assignment of OP. Moreover the site is read of many other users for which it  is interesting to see how to make the task and show how they would make the task.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that my answer is in a fictional dialect of Scheme without recursion built in because I was annoyed be the homework question and it leaves out the only tricky part, calling it "trivial"  I'll add a C version of the answer with the tricky part included ^^

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for your contribution. Please note that the answerer has confirmed my impression.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t implementation(size_t remainder, size_t shift, size_t result) {
    // long form:
    // while (remainder != 0 && remainder % 2 != 0)
    while (remainder % 2 != 0) {
        remainder /= 10;
    }
    if (remainder == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    size_t next_digit = (remainder % 10);
    size_t next_result = result + (next_digit * shift);
    return implementation(
            remainder / 10,
            shift * 10,
            next_result);
}

size_t even_digits(size_t input) {
    return implementation(input, 1, 0);
}
```